# Did any high-level French politician come out against the burkini ban in public swimming pools?

Tags: france, islam, secularism

As far as I can [tell](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-61883529) the Macron government and National Rally (Le Pen) have been against the burkini (thus calling for the ban). The high-profile left-wing candidates appear to have been very good [at avoiding the question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHjV5QtiMYs). So, did any high-level French politician (beyond the mayor of Grenoble) openly criticize the ban?

Comment: Why the DV?  Asking whether any mainstream, high-profile, politicians is on the record as seeing an issue with enforcing dress codes in religious matters, in a modern liberal democracy, seems perfectly on topic.  FWIW, Grenoble's mayor is allied with "the high profile left wing candidate" who prefers to demur.

Comment: Not sure about politicians per se, but the [CCIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_Against_Islamophobia_in_France) and the [LDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Rights_League_(France)) (both of which are NGOs) took legal action to overturn another such local ban in 2016. The official decision was apparently in their favor.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica "seems perfectly on topic." Intopic yes but that doesn't have to imply useful or well researched. Have not DVed but I can understand why somebody might think that knowing this isn't very helpful. A single politician is just an example, not very quantitative. I rather would know about polls about the matter.

Comment: @Trilarion Why is it not useful?  I'd be bloody concerned if my *politicians* were peddling "special rules for special religions".  Thankfully, I live in BC, Canada, as opposed to Quebec, Canada, or France, my birth country.   But if this was part of my province's political campaign differentiators, then yes, I'd want to know which politicians were pushing for these rules.  Not my much I could do about *polls*, but I sure could adjust my *vote* accordingly.

Comment: note that this type of banned swimwear would have been perfectly acceptable, even probably required, [in the early 1900s](https://fashionhistory.fitnyc.edu/a-history-of-womens-swimwear/).

Comment: @BrianZ: the current ban apparently applies only to pools but not beaches. https://www.politico.eu/article/france-court-confirm-ban-burkini-town-swimming-pool/ Seemingly because only the safety while swimming would be affected by the loose clothing... One has to wonder how they can prevent someone wearing one for going for a swim... in the sea/ocean.

Comment: And yeah, the reason why [most] politicians only seem to openly declare in one direction is that the polls on the matter also incline that way too https://www.voanews.com/a/burkini-disputes-resurface-in-southwestern-france-/6578863.html Also, the ban doesn't seem to be universal, but only in certain cities. The central government nonetheless challenged one city that removed its ban. Apparently Rennes removed their ban without a challenge.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica "Why is it not useful?" I cannot follow you. I don't live in France, I won't vote for any politician there. If I know that there exist one politician in France with a certain view, what have I learned? But you convinced me that the question would be interesting for French people.

Comment: @SJuan76: against the ban... clarified.

Comment: They don't have to come up explicitly in favor or against the burkini per se: only the far right presents it as a religious question, contrary to the French notion of laicity; more center politicians, like Macron, see it as *a question of public order* - burkini in swimming pools is contrary to the standard norms of hygiene, just like the men's long swimming trunks. Macron made this point vis-à-vis LePen during the first presidential debate in 2017 (I mean the debate with multiple candidates, before the first round of elections).

Comment: Another question, perhaps off-topic on Politics SE, would be whether there is any scientific justification for the bans on burkinis, swimsuits with arms, or board shorts (long, baggy shorts) from French swimming pools.

Comment: @RogerVadim: I think you may have missed the strong wording of the French government on these latest developments https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/73781/why-did-the-central-french-government-deem-the-lifting-of-the-burkini-ban-in-g

Comment: @Fizz Darmanin's personal opinions do not necessarily reflect those of the government - e.g., he is on the record comparing Yellow vests (Les gilets jaunes) to the Brownshirts. However, your question seems oddly formulated, as you yourself cite several high-level politicians speaking about it.